# Expand spinner downward as items are added...as well as adjust layout

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, spinner

I am making a form in an android app.  I currently have it in a relative layout with this snippet pictured below in a table layout within the relative layout:

[image]

When a user clicks on the spinner it pops up the selections. The user can select multiple selections and as of right now once the user hits ok it displays the selected on the spinner seperated by a comma.  However if the user chooses too many it will push the spinner to the right of it off the screen.  I was wondering if it would be possible to make the spinners display the text downward, so each selection would be on a new line and would shrink or expand the spinner given the amount selected.  Like so:

NorthEast:

|
Option1
|

|
Option2
|

|
Option3
|

South:

|
Select
|

This would also modify the whole layout so if the user selects a lot of options in northeast it will shift the south spinner downward.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a maxWidth to your spinner?

also you can try to wrap them in a linear layout (top two in one, bot ones in another for example) and set the layout to fill parent, and set the view's to fill parent and weight 1. that will give you equal widths of the spinners and restrict their width min/max value.

Comment: this only fixed the layout going off the screen..but that helps :) Thanks...still need to figure out how to get it to expand on new lines

Comment: try setting elipsise to None. if that doesn't work then you have to build your own spinner, or maybe populate a list below it with the selected arguments.